# How to remove starting dot on column notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I need to remove every starting dot in each column, example: .331497.201 needs to be 331497.201 and .R needs to be R
[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAifg.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression `(\s)(\.)` to find whitespaces followed by a dot and replace with `$1` (the whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

Use CTRL + H (replace) tool to replace the . with a blank space. You'll need to manually "next" your way through the document but the end result will be converting all of those pesky dots into blanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select a starting dot inclusive the tabulator and press `Ctrl + H`
2. In the Replace Dialog copy the value of `Search in` into `Replace with` and remove the dot
3. Click on Replace all

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\h)\.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=    # start lookbehind, make sure we have before
    \h  # 1 horizontal space (i.e. space or tabulation)
)       # end lookbehind
\.      # a dot
```